# Map app not working

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, dictionary, mapkit

Have a look at the below code it's working properly

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f", 23.0300, 72.5800, 22.3000, 70.7833];    
NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

but it opens map in safari browser.

after that i've tried below code

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f", 23.0300, 72.5800, 22.3000, 70.7833];    
NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

it open map app as i desired but not giving me the directional result with route or the same result that above google map gives how can i achieve the result as first code in map app?

please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Apple's map does not have the same API as google maps, thus you URL will not work. With iOS 6 apple introduced the [`MKMapItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html) which allows developers to interact with the maps.app.

If you want to keep using the the maps via http then you should change you url:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f", 23.0300, 72.5800, 22.3000, 70.7833];    
NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

As stated in the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) you should not add the `/maps/` path.

> URLs that contain no path parameters or that contain specific map
>   paths are opened in Safari and displayed there. For example, URLs
>   based on the paths http://maps.apple.com/, http://maps.apple.com/maps,
>   http://maps.apple.com/local, and http://maps.apple.com/m are all
>   opened in Safari. To open a URL in the Maps app, the path must be of
>   the form http://maps.apple.com/?q.
>
> The rules for creating a valid map link are as follows:
>
> - The domain must be maps.apple.com.
> - The path cannot be /maps/*.
> - A parameter cannot be q=* if the value is a URL (so KML is not picked up).
> - The parameters cannot include view=text or dirflg=r

Comment: still unable to locate route as google map does with your code.

Comment: That is because the Apple maps works differently then Google maps. You will not be able to do a direct conversion. I would suggest that you use [`MKMapItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html) but it will require an address as wel as coordinate. Also as you can read in the Apple documentation the `daddr` & `saddr` require an address not a location.

Comment: okay, So i guess it's better to open the google map on safari rather then apple map on map app... lol :D